# Microsoft OneDrive or Google Drive - which one is more secure option?

Tags: onedrive, google-drive, cloud-storage

I want to choose cloud storage for my private stuff, especially for the photography - which services is better ? I know the Google Photos but it's also in the Google Drive scope so please could you tell which services look more secure? I want to choose cloud only from these two because of pricing.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by security because either way you are giving your stuff to someone else to store on their computer.

Comment: Google and Microsoft both have adequate protections in place to secure their user data.  One is no more secure than the other, however Google, like Facebook, is an advert company at their core, so they do data mine from user data (for example, Google data mines from Gmail, whereas Microsoft does not from Outlook [previously Hotmail]).

Comment: @JW0914 - However, Microsoft also a advert company, even if it's a secondary business (Bing).

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft doesn't data mine in the way that Google and Facebook do... i.e. Microsoft does not data mine from their email service, whereas Google does.  Google's, like Facebook's, primary business is as an advert agency, whereas Microsoft's is software, with a side business as a small advert agency, specifically for Bing.  I'm unsure if Google data mines from photos uploaded to their servers, so I thought it was prudent to at least mention the data mining in my previous comment for awareness.